# How to see the complete default mapping in Vim?

Tags: key-bindings, help-system

I know about `:map` but I want to list the complete default mapping list with the associated help for each mapping.

Otherwise I need to test each command manually such as `:help CTRL-B`

Is there any comprehensive list of all the Vim mappings that use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key?

Comment: Note that the second answer on the other question is probably better than the top/accepted one ;-)